# Symfony OneToOne Doctrine like in QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, query-builder, doctrine-query

like in symfony's query builder doesn't work and show me error!

this is my query:

```
    $apiToken = $this->createQueryBuilder('ud')
        ->select('ud.apiToken')
        ->where('ud.user LIKE :userPhone')
        ->setParameter('userPhone','%'.$phone)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

    return $apiToken;
```

and this is the error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 64 near 'user LIKE :u': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

cant find any extension stuff for like in query builder or useful description!

this is my UserDevice Entity:

```
class UserDevice implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="notification_token",type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $notificationToken;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="api_token" , type="string", unique=true, nullable=true)
     */
    private $apiToken;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="device", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_phone", referencedColumnName="phone")
     */
    private $user;

}
```

Comment: Is ud.user really a phone number?  I would think user would be an object with a phone property.  In which case you would left join user then do your like clause on user.phone.  Just speculating.

Comment: @Cerad no its ok problem is (like expression) in qb

Comment: @sina, Can You show your `Entity` pls?

Comment: @sina Okay.  Interesting that your error message does not match your posted code.

Comment: is ud.user a string or an entity? I.e. as a wild guess with this limited information, you might be missing the user table join from your query (and the where clause should be accessing user.phonenumber field)... As asked above, including your entity code would clarify the situation.

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev i added entity to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `join` query between table `UserDevice` and `User`.

```
$apiToken = $this->createQueryBuilder('ud')
        ->select('ud.apiToken')
        ->where('u.phone LIKE :userPhone') // here Users phone field
        ->innerJoin('ud.user', 'u')
        ->setParameter('userPhone','%'.$phone)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

return $apiToken;
```